# How to block mails from a server in gmail

Tags: email-server, spam, gmail

I am getting mails daily from different mail address like

> ry8029@fastmail.fm
>
> ry1532@outlook.com

etc.

Since , the mail Id is changing daily , I can't filter those mails.

I checked that mail origin .

> X-Received: by 10.224.75.69 with SMTP id
>
> x5mr811082qaj.39.1381914914355;
>
> ```
>     Wed, 16 Oct 2013 02:15:14 -0700 (PDT) Return-Path: <ry8029@fastmail.fm>
> ```
>
> Received: from server.rupyen.info
>
> (server.rupyen.info. [173.245.7.224])
>
> ```
>     by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id c11si34872774qey.80.1969.12.31.16.00.00
>
>     (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
>
>     Wed, 16 Oct 2013 02:15:14 -0700 (PDT) Received-SPF: neutral (google.com:
> ```
>
> 173.245.7.224 is neither permitted nor denied by domain
>
> of ry8029@fastmail.fm) client-ip=173.245.7.224;

I found that for every mail , server is same : server.rupyen.info

How can I block / spam ? filter these mails ?

Comment: Mark them as spam and Gmail should quickly catch on.

Comment: Mail ID is changing daily , so even if I put one mail as spam , I am receiving other mails.

Answer (score 1):

You can try filtering by using the has words fields recieved by. Something similar was asked here:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/is-it-possible-to-create-a-gmail-filter-that-works-on-headers-other-than-from-t